# Why Won't My Variable Declarations Work?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using VBA to write a program in PowerPoint. I want specific code to run with the OnSlideShowPageChange() event. I know for sure that the event itself works because this code runs fine:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
MsgBox("Hello")
End Sub
```

I want to run code that defines Global variables on *slide 1 **only***, and I use the following code:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim CurSlide As Integer
CurSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
If CurSlide = 1 Then
    Public Var1 As Integer
    Public Var2 As Integer
    Var1 = 0
    Var2 = 0
    Public Var3 As String
    Var3 = "MyString"
End If
End Sub
```

The second example is where I have trouble. The code runs on slide 1 only, *but* when I place a MsgBox like this: `MsgBox(Var1 & Var2 & Var3)` the MsgBox will not appear. I think there is something wrong with the declarations, but I'm not sure what it is. 
Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander, No that was different. In the other question, user6439024 was trying to get the ID to remain the same when slides are reordered. My question is why won't the `MsgBox("My code here")` run when the slide is 1.

Comment: Works for me PPT2013

Comment: @TimWilliams, That may be part of the problem. I am using PowerPoint **2016.**

Comment: Does your code run at all?  If Yes what's the value of CurSlide when you're on the first slide?

Comment: @TimWilliams, After I start the slideshow, the code does run actually. (The value of CurSlide is 1 on slide 1; it is always the same as the slide number.) That means that the problem must be in the code that usually replaces `MsgBox("My code here")` I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: Public variables need to be declared outside of any procedure - typically at the top of the module.  You can't declare them in your sub, but you can set their values.

Comment: @TimWilliams, It worked! Thanks so much! Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public/global variables need to be declared outside of any procedure - typically at the top of the module.

You can't declare them in your sub, but you can set their values.

```
Public Var1 As Integer
Public Var2 As Integer
Public Var3 As String

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()

    Dim CurSlide As Integer
    CurSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
    If CurSlide = 1 Then
        Var1 = 0
        Var2 = 0
        Var3 = "MyString"
    End If

End Sub
```